# How to solve this limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{2^n}{n^k})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

It's not allowed to apply L'Hopital's rule .

I tried using binomial distribution $2^n=(1+1)^n$ in order to manipulate with numerator but don't know what to do with denominator.

P.s Should i use Squeeze Theorem to this kind of limit .
I need help with this Calculus I problem ...

Comment: Do you mean $2^n/n^n$?

Comment: @S.Maths its an Uni exam problem ,hardly to think it has been made a mistake to formulate it :)

Comment: I didn't think so but you didn't say anything about $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the logarithm of the expression (assuming $k \ge 1$)

$$
\ln\left(\frac{2^n}{n^k}\right) =\ln(2^n)-\ln(n^k) = n\ln(2) +\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^k} \right)
$$
It follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{2^n}{n^k}\right)
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[n\ln(2) +\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^k} \right)\right] \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}(n\ln(2)) + \lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^k} \right) \\
&=+\infty + 0 = +\infty
\end{align}
So the limit of the logarithm is $+\infty$ and so is the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2^n}{n^k}\right) = +\infty.
$$
Simply explained: $\ln(x) \to +\infty \implies x \to +\infty$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac{2^n}{n^k}$.

$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 2\frac{n^k}{(n+1)^k}=2\left(\frac{n}{n+1} \right)^k =2\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1} \right )^k.$$

Since $k$ is fixed, for large $n$ this ratio exceeds, say $\frac 32$, so $\lim a_n = \infty$.

Comment: It's a variety of the comparison test.  You're showing that it's larger than something you already know diverges: $C (\frac 32)^{n-N_0}$ where $C \gt 0$.

Comment: yes, but what is the thing that should diverge

Comment: See the revision to my comment.  I'd like you to develop some feel for what's going on rather than just giving you the answer.

Comment: But for large $n$, i.e., $n \to \infty$ the ratio seems to approach $2$, right ?

Comment: Yes, which means that at some point it's always greater than $\frac 32$, which is all that you need.  In fact, all you really need is that the ratio is eventually always greater than $1+ \varepsilon$ for some fixed $\varepsilon \gt 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $k>0$. Let $m=[k]+1$. Then, for $n>2m+2$
$$ \frac{2^n}{n^k}=\frac{(1+1)^n}{n^k}\ge \frac{\binom{n}{m}}{n^{m+1}}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m!n^{m+1}}\ge \frac{(n-m+1)^{n-m}}{m!n^{m+1}}=\frac{1}{m!}(1-\frac{m}{n})^{m+1}(n-m)^{n-2m-1} $$
Since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{m!}(1-\frac{m}{n})^{m+1}(n-m)^{n-2m-1}=\infty $$
hence one has
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n}{n^k}=\infty. $$

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^k}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{e^{n\ln(2)}}{e^{k\ln(n)}}=  \lim_{n\to+\infty}e^{n(\ln(2)-k\frac{\ln(n)}{n}) } 
$$
Note that
$$
\lim _{n\to+\infty} k\frac{\ln(n)} {n} =0$$

So :

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^k}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} e^{n\ln(2)}=+\infty $$

Because $\ln(2)>0$.